# Fuzzing virtual drivers tools

Tags: windows, security, virtualization, virtual-machine, fuzzing

I'm looking to fuzz virtual drivers, I've read the other questions about this but they don't really go anywhere. Basically looking to see if there's an obvious tool I've missed and want to know if fuzzing IOCTLs from a windows guest would work? Or if I need to write one in low level eg IN/OUT?

Any tools out there for fuzzing drivers in a windows guest to hit the hypervisor either hyper-v or VMware

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to exercise virtualization code.

First, of course, if you're on Windows, is the IOCTL interface.

Then you should remember that all virtual devices are emulated in some way by some code in the guest OS and in the host OS. So, accessing input devices (keyboard and mouse), video device, storage (disks), network card, communication ports (serial, parallel), standard PC devices (PIC, PIT, RTC, DMA), CPU APIC, etc etc will also exercise virtualization code.

It's also very important to remember that virtualization of the various PC devices (unless we're talking about synthetic devices working over the VMBUS in Windows) is done by intercepting, parsing and emulating/executing instructions that access device memory-mapped buffers and registers and I/O ports. This gives you yet another "interface" to pound on.

By using it you might uncover not only device-related bugs but also instruction-related bugs. If you're interested in the latter, you need to have a good understanding of how the x86 CPU works at the instruction level in various modes (real, virtual 8086, protected, 64-bit), how it handles interrupts and exceptions and you'll also need to know how to access those PC devices (how and at what memory addresses and I/O port numbers).

Btw, Windows won't let you directly access these things unless your code is running in the kernel. You may want to have a non-Windows guest VM for things like this just to avoid overprotective functionality of Windows. Look for edge cases, unusual instruction encodings (including invalid encodings) or unusual instructions for usual tasks (e.g. using FPU/MMX/SSE/etc or special protected-mode instructions (like SIDT) to access devices). Think and be naughty.

Another thing to consider is race conditions and computational or I/O load. You may have some luck exploring in that direction too.

Comment: Cool thanks, are there any neat tools already available for doing these things? I've seen ioctlfuzzer but that's about it.

Comment: Would ioctlfuzzer then bee a good place to start then? since it says it fuzzes IOCTLs in a windows device randomly.